# USB PHY 2.0 Webcam's Mic Work in Windows, but not work in linux

Tags: usb, webcam, microphone

I have a webcam, SPC WC02, webcam. It works in Windows, but not works in linux. I test it with `https://mictests.com/`, When I test in linux, the website give me a message `The audio track is paused.`.

Here is my `amixer -c1` result:

```
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 4096
  Mono: Capture 4096 [100%] [16.00dB] [on]
```

When I open `alsamixer -c1`, there is a message `This sound device does not have any playback controls.`.

How to fix it?

I will update my question if this information need more detail.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Have you looked in `pavucontrol` ?

Comment: @guiverc KDE Neon, based on ubuntu Focal Fossa. Yes, I already checked in pavucontrol

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Comment: @guiverc It based Ubuntu Focal Fossa.